# Firebase IOS : Warning "setScreenName:screenClass: must be called after a view controller has appeared"

Tags: ios, firebase, google-tag-manager

I want to understand the warning I am getting from Firbase IOS

```
<FIRAnalytics/WARNING> setScreenName:screenClass: must be called after a view controller has appeared
```

My info.plist contains

```
FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled = NO
```

I am calling

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    recordScreenView()    
}

func recordScreenView() {
    // title from the story board
    // These strings must be <= 36 characters long in order for setScreenName:screenClass: to succeed.
    guard let screenName = title else {
        return
    }
    let screenClass = classForCoder.description()

    // [START set_current_screen]
     GCITracking.sharedInstance.trackSetScreenName(screenName, screenClass: screenClass)
    // [END set_current_screen]
}
```

code taken from sample app

I am not seeing my screen event as expected but I am not sure whether this has anything to do with my code or is a GTM configuration issue.

I found the warning message ambigious

Comment: Is there a solution to this yet ? @Ryan Heitner

Comment: @Florentt I want an explanation of the warning, not sure if there is an issue or not.

Comment: I have the same issue, I guess because I'm using a container view controller with embedded childviewcontrollers, and I'm calling setScreenName:screenClass from viewDidAppear of those children VCs. Is it possible that it's also your case?

Comment: No not the same setup, was using some container views wanted to call manually.

Comment: please what is the screen class? I'm using objective-c. Have I to put the viewController name?

Comment: @cdf1982 I am facing the same issue and I have a very similar setup to your's. I will share if I come across a solution.

Comment: @Ne AS if you send nil for screen class, Firebase should still be able to track the original screen class i.e. [FIRAnalytics setScreenName:@"Home Screen" screenClass:nil]; so if your class is lets say "HomeViewController", passing nil will default to "HomeViewController", at least that is what I understood from the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Just faced this problem with a GTM + Firebase implementation and made the warning disappear simply by calling this method in the **viewDidAppear** method :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated);
        // ...
        Analytics.setScreenName(screenName, screenClass: screenClass)
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wont this log a pageview every time your view appears? Even when poping back to it from a later view controller?

Comment: That's very likely, I didn't think about that. Unfortunately, I don't work on my mobile projects anymore, it would be great if you or someone else could test it and post a new answer, or update this one if the results are wrong and another solution exists.

Comment: I either log the analytics in ViewDidLoad (which will not work if your VC is embedded in a TabBarController, since the viewDidLoad gets called before the user actually tries to load see the view), or create a flag that only lets the analytics event run once, in viewDidAppear. I'll try to test my theory of the above running multiple times and post here.

Answer (score 0):

***For Firebase (v6.29.0*)***

declare this in `viewDidAppear`

```swift
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: "myScreenName"])
```